# How many writes does this count as? [Firestore]

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'example').document(u'example1')

doc_ref.update({
        u'value1': 'data1',
        u'value2': data2
    }, firestore.CreateIfMissingOption(True))
```

If I am only changing values within 1 document here, is it considered as 1 count or 2?

And if value1 is now an array instead of a string, data1 = [a,b,c], is this considered as still 1 write or 3 writes now ?

Answer (score 1):

One call to `update` is one write, no matter how many fields are updated.  Similarly, one call to `get` is one read, no matter how many fields are read.